# Getting error with grunt protractor

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, gruntjs, protractor

I have installed java for grunt with this command:

```
npm install grunt-run-java --save-dev
```

and then I put `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run-java');` into my grunt file. After that, when I try to run grunt protractor, it is throwing the following error:

```
Running "protractor:chrome" (protractor) task
WARNING - You have specified both capabilites and multiCapabilities. This will result in capabilities being ignored
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn java ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:17)
>> events.js:141
>>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>>       ^
>>
>> Error: spawn java ENOENT
>>     at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
>>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
>>     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
>>     at doNTCallback2 (node.js:452:9)
>>     at process._tickCallback (node.js:366:17)
>> Test failed but keep the grunt process alive.
```

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Does Java task need to run before other task? I guess that atm they r running async

Comment: Unsure what the relation is to protractor, are you launching selenium server from grunt? Maybe try `grunt-protractor-runner`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are including both `capabilities` and `multiCapabilities`. You should have one or the other. Since they are ignored, selenium server does not know which browser your test will run.